# Increase column values by 1 which satisfy some condition

Tags: matlab, matrix

In MATLAB, I have a 10x14 matrix.

How can I increase all *positive* numbers that appear in the first 6 columns and less than 5, by 1?

Of cause, I don't want to use for loop. I expect a more elegant way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
A(:,1:6) = A(:,1:6) + (A(:,1:6) < 5 & A(:,1:6) > 0)
```

Where A is your Matrix